# a good way of passing multiple values from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

This is something happening everyday

I'm looking for a better way of grabbing the values from view into the action, since the controller create and destroy based on http request, is there a good way to pass all the params thru?(By that I mean more than 5 params)

I think about session but there is a chance pepple lose their session and the important value gone, besides session, is there any other way around?

Comment: What are those parameters? Are they parameters required by the View that need to be transferred from View to View through the Action?

Comment: In my case yes, Say I have a list, when people enter the keywords I should give them a filtered, new list, but if they click the page number, all the keyword, as well as the list gone, all they see is that original one

Comment: @LifeScript The page number links could include the keywords in the querystring.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to maintain the querystring between different actions. If that's right, look at my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466682/instantiate-a-helper-class-but-not-in-view/

Answer (score 2):

I would first consider whether your application needs to save that much information between views. MVC is a REST based architecture, and is typically designed to be stateless.

With that said, your options for passing around state with a user boil down to Session, Cookies, and Database.

I would create a static class that stores and retrieves its data from session.

```
public static class CustomPersistStore
{
   public static CustomClass Current{
      get{
         var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session["key"] as CustomClass;
         if(instance = null) {
            instance = new CustomClass();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass values from the View to the Action the best practice is to use strongly typed views.

http://howmvcworks.net/OnViews/BuildingAStronglyTypedView